# Skeleton CSS - hiding content from mobiles

Tags: css, mobile, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have used Bootstrap extensively and regularly used the css classes to hide various elements from mobile view. Does Skeleton CSS have a similar thing for hiding content on a mobile?

Comment: You could just use the media queries (they have some predefined) and then hide the content that you want to hide? I do not understand the question..

Comment: Thanks mate, i will do that.. i just wondered if it had preset individual classes for doing this like in Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a media query example below:

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .someStyle {
        background-color: display: none;
    }
}